# cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libva-drm.so.1 even though I installed libva-dev and libva2

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

In the linking process of my executable, I get this:

```
[ 85%] Linking CXX executable rosek_qml
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libva-drm.so.1, needed by ../bin/libCTMedia_codec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libva.so.1, needed by ../bin/libCTMedia_codec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
[100%] Built target rosek_qml
```

I never got this error before. Normally it'd simply refuse to finish the linking. But in this case, it did finish. Why?
When I run the executable, I get

```
./rosek_qml: error while loading shared libraries: libva-drm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even though I installed `libva2` and `libva-dev`.

Here's my CMake file:

```
add_library(ctmedia_codec SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(ctmedia_drm SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(ctstream SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ctmedia_codec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/libCTMedia_codec.so)
set_target_properties(ctmedia_drm PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/libCTMedia_drm.so)
set_target_properties(ctstream PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/libCTStream.so)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
    tesseract -lpthread
    ctmedia_codec
    ctmedia_drm
    ctstream
    -lva
    -lva-drm 
    )
```

Comment: The error is about missed files `libva.so.1` and `libva-drm.so.1`. Do you **actually** have these files? Probably, among installed with `libva-dev` or so.

Comment: Fedora, CentOS: libva → `/usr/lib64/libva-drm.so.1` ... Debian, Ubuntu: libva → `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so` ... but no `libva-drm.so.1` **!**